# Is there any relation between Bane and the Korean smugglers?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy

In The Dark Knight, Bruce goes on a love boat with all the ballerinas as an alibi to catch Lau from his building and bring him to Gotham.

He therefore hires Korean Smugglers who below the radar to move in and out of China without being noticed.

Now the smugglers pick up Bruce Wayne from the boat and then when the Batman catches Lau they help him escape with a sky hook. Therefore as reason suggests,the smugglers must know about Batman's identity...

Now In The Dark Knight Rises, Bane is shown to be the leader of an extremist group. He was ex communicated from the League of Shadows before Ra's Al Ghul took Bruce in and trained him. Bane must be keeping track of Batman's whereabouts and therefore might have come in contact with those smugglers. Now is there any way that Bane learns of Batman's true identity from those smugglers instead of the members of the League Of Shadows...

Is there a word of God from director or story writer about this?

Comment: Nope. The script and novel both indicates that Bane most likely learned of Bruce's identity while he was a member of the League's inner circle. Don't forget that his mentor is Ra's daughter so even if Bane hadn't been told, his boss sure as hell knows from her daddy.

Comment: I'm not sure you can link the smugglers to the adventure with the sky hook. All we know about that is that Fox was organising it.

Comment: @Richard Talia Al Ghul is never shown to have been told by Ra's nor is there any discussion about it in the movies.

Comment: That's true, but it's mentioned in the novelisation and I see no reason why he wouldn't have told her if he was grooming her as his replacement. If anything, you'd need to think of a blindingly good reason why he wouldn't have told her...